# how to get OS name in Windows Powershell using functions

Tags: function, powershell, operating-system, wmi

I'm trying to return OS name using functions in Windows Powershell.

I built this code, but i don't get any results. Any help please?

```
Function Get-OSName
{
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Name
}
"Name of the OS: $(Get-OSName)"
```

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Works absolutely fine for me.

Comment: Same here, even though I'd use Caption instead of Name.

Comment: @arco444 can you please check updated post and see my result

Comment: @MickyBalladelli can you please check updated post and see my result

Comment: You should save that into a PS1 file and invoke the file, or press Return one more time :). The >> prompt means it's waiting for more.

Comment: well now it is clear to you that i'm new to powershell :) thank you very much for that. it works perfectly now :D. I think you should write the answer in different way so i can mark it is the "right one"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have omitted a critical part of your screen, with your image. What is
important is the line directly after the last line shown. If the last line shown
is truly the last, then you still need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once more.
Consider this command

```
PS > 'hello world'
hello world
```

Notice the result printed as soon as I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. However certain
actions, like defining a function cause PowerShell to enter interactive mode.
Once PowerShell is in interactive mode it will require pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>
twice to start the evaluation. Example

```
PS > function foo {
>> echo bar
>> }
>> 'hello world'
>> 'dog bird mouse'
>>
hello world
dog bird mouse
```

Notice this time around I was able to enter a command after the same
`'hello world'` command.

Answer (score 5):

Try exploring the object to find out what property you want:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | select -Property *
```

You will notice the 'Caption' property contains the friendly OS name, as micky-balladelli mentioned.  Your example would change to:

```
Function Get-OSName
{
    (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: caption is indeed a better choice, thanks on that...but still it doesnt return any results. can you please check my updated post?